# Drupal views in installation profile

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-views

Is there a possibility to configure/create views in an installation profile?
I have been searching on the internet for quite some time now but I can't find any info about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I think the best option would be manage your View in code (represented as a custom module). See [this blogpost](http://www.deckfifty.com/blog/2012-02/using-drupal-views-code) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Features module to export your view In a module and just enable this module in installation profile, or you can rather implement hook_views_default_views and have a default view exported in code.

Comment: when I add the function `hook_views_default_views()` and all the (export) code, still nothing happens. Is this function supposed to be in my .install file then?

Comment: Never mind, got it fixed. It is supposed to be in the .profile file.